# Confusion regarding inductor connected to an AC source

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Suppose I connect an inductor to an ac source. Now a time varying current is produced and this causes change in  magnetic flux linked with inductor coils and hence an induced  is generated. But why this induced emf has to equal the applied emf? I have came across many resources stating Kirchoff law,  but that does not help.

Comment: Is this the sort of argument "that does not help"?  $$\mathscr E_{source} - L \frac{dI}{dt} = IR,$$ so for $R=0$,  $$\mathscr E_{source} = L \frac{dI}{dt}. $$ I ask so we can try and come up with another way of presenting the argument if necessary.

Comment: @Philip wood you got it right.

Comment: I've written an answer. I suspect that you won't like it!

Answer (score 0):

$\mathscr E_{source}$, the work done per unit charge *on* charge passing through the source, is equal to $L \frac{dI}{dt}$, the work done per unit charge *by* charge going through the inductor (increasing the energy in its magnetic field). Why equal? Because, if $R=0$, there's nothing apart from the inductor and the source in the circuit for work to be done on or by!